# Spinner Progressbar in android

Tags: android

I want to implement `ProgressBar` in Android and when I execute the program, `Progressbar` should show for up to 2 seconds. I can't get it to work properly but I can't figure out why.

```
public void myThread(){
    Thread th=new Thread(){

     @Override
     public void run(){
      try
      {

       while(mRunning)
       {

       Thread.sleep(10L);//10s wait
       YourCurrentActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            //DISMISS PROGRESS BAR HERE


        mRunning=false;
        }
       });
       }
      }catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
   }
     }
    };
    th.start();
   }
```

I have tried this but it does not giving me output as i want.

Comment: Where do you even have a ProgressBar?

Comment: I've cleaned it up as best as I can but you need to explain what is/isn't happening and what you expect to happen.

Answer (score 0):

That what handlers are for in Android.
Example:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    { 
       // cancel or dismiss your progressbar
    }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: okay let me try it now then i will inform u okay dear.and yes thank u so much

Comment: Hello dear yet it progresssing i want to stop it but it does not.please suggest more.

Comment: Please help me someone please.

Comment: Hello Dear Carsten very good thing 4 me and thank u so much i got the solution yesterday ur code were not working bcz i forgot to dismiss it but now its working so again thank u so much.

Comment: And yes Very good morning to u.and pls if u dnt mind than may i khow ur email address please bcz i m new in android and by ur help i can improve it easily plaese dnt mind and please give me ur contact details pls.